# Microsoft Access Append VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to automate records from a query to append to a table if the ID does not exist. While running into issues, I have even tried to use VBA from some other databases I know this is working on and put it into the targeted database. Still, I am receiving the same error. It is highlighting "dbs as Database" when the error appears.

Error- "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined"

```
Function HistoricTable()

Dim dbs As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef


Set dbs = CurrentDb

dbs.Execute "insert into [Destination_Table]  SELECT * FROM [Query Name]  "



End Function
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you copy-paste the code or you typed it? When you type the space immediately after `As`, is `Database` in the list of available types? If not, you get this error.

Comment: [Check this Q&A out as it may be helpful](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/compile-error-user-defined-type-not-defined-on-dim/d21efe0f-987d-4aaa-a3f7-5bcf677158b4)

Comment: That reference was very helpful. Looks like my issue is cured from there. Thank you all for your help!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be something like this.

```
INSERT INTO target [(field1[, field2[, …]])]
VALUES (value1[, value2[, …]])
```

See the link below for more info.

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/snytax/append-query.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a reference to the DAO library in the VBA editor. In my old Access it's in the menu `Tools > References...`

[image]

You can also remove the ADODB library (the other database access technology).